# Is roasting the same thing as broiling?

Tags: roasting

My electric oven just has two settings: broil and bake.

I have a recipe that calls for "roasting" a duck at 400 degrees. Is that the same thing as broiling or is it baking?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming an electric oven as typically seen in the US:

Roasting is the same setting as baking. The words mean slightly different things, but not to your electric oven.

Using the baking setting has the heat coming from the bottom of the oven, broiling has it coming from the top. The temperature is usually set very high to broil (if it can be set at all, some ovens only broil on the highest setting). Baking can be done at any temperature within the range of the oven.

What is called broiling in the US is called grilling in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

In my electric oven, broil uses the top burner and is at Hi or Lo temp only, roasting uses the same top element but temp can be controlled as in baking. Baking uses the bottom element and temp can be controlled.

Comment: Welcome to the site. That's a good explanation of how an electric oven generally behaves. Explaining how that impacts roasting or baking or broiling would more directly answer the question.